# Solve trig limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{12z^2+6\sin^2z-18(\cos z \sin z)z} {\sin^4z}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{12z^2+6\sin^2z-18(\cos z \sin z)z} {\sin^4z}$$

where $z$ goes to $0$.

Have been eyeballing it for quite a while, but without any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried?  What techniques are available to you?  Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: @RobertShore oops, totally forgot about the L'HOpital's rule... I'm technically in the complex analysis now, so it slipped my mind. This should be quite easy now... I tried combinign terms, and adding and substracting, but whitout any luck. i wonder if you can solve it without the l'hopital's rule

Comment: Use series expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\sin x = x - \frac16x^3+O(x^5)$ and expand the numerator to order $z^4$, matching the leading order of the denominator,

$$12z^2+6\sin^2z-18(\cos z \sin z)z$$
$$=12z^2+6(z-\frac16z^3)^2-9z\sin2z+O(z^6)$$
$$=12z^2+6z^2-2z^4-9z\left(2z-\frac16(2z)^3\right)+O(z^6)$$
$$=-2z^4+12z^4+O(z^6)$$
$$=10z^4+O(z^6)$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{12z^2+6\sin^2z-18(\cos z \sin z)z} {\sin^4z}
=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{10z^4} {z^4}=10$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

$$\dfrac{y^2-\sin^2y}{y^4}=\dfrac{1+1}{3!}$$

Now observe that $$12z^2+6\sin^2z-18z(\cos z\sin z)=-6(z^2-\sin^2z)+9z(2z-\sin2z)$$